# How to know on which drive an Java Application is installed?

Tags: java

Is there already an existing object/method able to tell us on which drive our running Java Application is installed ?

Thanks.

Farid

Answer (score 4):

Try the following on Windows:

```
File file = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile();
File root = file.getParentFile();
while (root.getParentFile() != null) {
    root = root.getParentFile();
}
System.out.println("Drive is: "+root.getPath());
```

On Unix systems, this will be less useful as the root will always be /

Answer (score 0):

Check this example: http://littletutorials.com/2008/03/10/getting-file-system-details-in-java/

On Windows environment you could read the HOMEDRIVE variable.
If you run this code you will see all the environment variables available.

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n", envName, env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

HOMEDRIVE doesn't exist as a concept in Unix environments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [java.io.File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) javadoc:

> The parent of an abstract pathname may
>   be obtained by invoking the
>   [getParent()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29) method of this class and
>   consists of the pathname's prefix and
>   each name in the pathname's name
>   sequence except for the last. Each
>   directory's absolute pathname is an
>   ancestor of any File  object with an
>   absolute abstract pathname which
>   begins with the directory's absolute
>   pathname. For example, the directory
>   denoted by the abstract pathname
>   "/usr" is an ancestor of the directory
>   denoted by the pathname
>   "/usr/local/bin".
>
> The prefix concept is used to handle
>   root directories on UNIX platforms,
>   and drive specifiers, root directories
>   and UNC pathnames on Microsoft Windows
>   platforms, as follows:
>
> - For UNIX platforms, the prefix of an absolute pathname is always "/".
>     Relative pathnames have no prefix. The
>     abstract pathname denoting the root
>     directory has the prefix "/" and an
>     empty name sequence.
> - For Microsoft Windows platforms, the prefix of a pathname that contains a drive specifier consists of the drive letter followed by ":" and possibly followed by "\\" if the pathname is absolute. The prefix of a UNC pathname is "\\\\"; the hostname and the share name are the first two names in the name sequence. A relative pathname that does not specify a drive has no prefix.

So a solution might be to create a relative `File` object (use `"."` for the current directory), get the parent and extract the drive letter. This is of course not portable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the current working directory of the running system, you use the following:

```
String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This will tell you the directory it was started in, which is often where the Jar file is located, or the root of the classpath is located.

Edit:
The [System Class javadoc for the method getProperties()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) has the common set of System properties that are available.